# How to pass Seq[(model, Seq[model2])] to Scala Play framework 2.5 view?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Trying to pass a sequence to scala view in a controller. View header looks like this:

```
@(dModels: Seq[(dModel, Seq[dModelCondition])])(implicit request: RequestHeader, messages: Messages, loggedUser: User)
```

Compilation error:

```
Cannot write an instance of Seq[(models.dModel, Seq[models.dModelCondition])] => play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable to HTTP response. Try to define a Writeable[Seq[(models.dModel, Seq[models.dModelCondition])] => play.twirl.api.HtmlFormat.Appendable]
```

Edit: added controller action code

```
def index = silhouette.SecuredAction.async { implicit request =>
dModelDao.all().map {
  models: Seq[dModel] => {
    Future.sequence(models.map(plantModel => {
      for {
        conditions <- plantDiseaseConditionDao.findByModelId(plantModel.id)
      } yield (plantModel, conditions)
    }))
  }
}.map(_ => Ok(views.html.plant_models(_)))
```

}

Any ideas how to define such a Writable and where it should stick. Workarounds?

Comment: Please attach your Controller code. Probably there is an error.

Comment: Thank you for asking. Added.

Answer (score 1):

Use other character instead of _ in map. It works for me.

`.map(s => Ok(views.html.plant_models(s)))`

Comment: Can't accept an answer since didn't touch that project for few months

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not to do with your params. If you have changed your templates params its more than likely (as they do not have defaults) that your controller which using the template now has incorrect params. Hence the error.